# iOS9: Title doesn't appear after I hide SegmentedControl in the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I have a `UISegmentedControl` on a `UINavigationBar`.  The `UIViewController` is embedded inside a `UINavigationController` Screen shot from the storyboard, see below:

[image]

If the device is an `iPad`, I would like to hide the `UISegmentedControl` and show a `self.title` instead.

In my `viewDidLoad`, I have the code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        segmentedControlNavBar.hidden = true
        self.title = "Navigation Title"       

    } else {
        segmentedControlNavBar.hidden = false
        navigationItem.prompt = "Navigation Title"
        self.title = nil
    }
}
```

**Resul (From Simulator):**

[image]

I also tried `viewWillAppear`, but no avail.

If I take out the `UISegmentedControl` from the `Storyboard`, the `UINavigationBar` Title appears fine.

How can I hide the `UISegmentedControl` from the navigation bar and show a title?

**EDIT**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    segmentedControlMain.hidden = true
    navigationItem.prompt = nil
    title = "Navigation Title"
    let items = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.items
    print(items?.first?.title)
```

}

Log:  Optional("Navigation Title")

I guess it's there, how do I get the UINavigationBar to show it?

These did not work:

```
    self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the topitem from the UINavigationBar is changed instead of being a UILabel to a UISegmentedControl you might do a NSLog of the data contained inside the [UINavigationBar items] to see how are they ordered, cause it will render the topmost item.

> "The navigation controller creates the navigation bar automatically and pushes and pops navigation items when appropriate"

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/items

Comment: I think we need more info to debug this thing out, but if "hidden = true" is not working sometimes calling the setter method works (don't ask me why) [segmentedControlMain setHidden:YES];

Double check your connections between the segmentedControlMain and the view, also a hack may be to change the alpha settings of the segmentedControlMain to 0.0 to make it transparent

Comment: Segmented Control is hidden.  But the title is not appearing.

Comment: Then maybe try this:

self.navigationController.topItem.title = @"Hello World";

Comment: Try setting the segmented control nav bar to nil.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread but the below worked for me:

1. set the titleView of the navigationItem to nil: self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
2. then set the title to the desired title: self.title = "Desired Title"